OCFS2 on Google Cloud Platform GCP/GCE - FATAL: Module ocfs2_dlmfs not found linux-modules-extra
I installed OCFS2 on my google cloud server, when I try bringing o2cb online, I get this error:
Loading filesystem "ocfs2_dlmfs": Unable to load filesystem "ocfs2_dlmfs" Failed
The ocfs2 package I installed on my google server is from:
https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/ocfs2-tools
and I installed ocfs2-tools like this:   apt install -y ocfs2-tools
Here is the ocfs2 version I have installed:
  root@lampstack-vm:~# dpkg -l | grep ocfs
  ii ocfs2-tools 1.8.7-1+b1 amd64 tools for managing OCFS2 cluster filesystems


I can see the ocfs2 cluster status as shown here:
  root@lampstack-vm:~# service o2cb status
  o2cb.service - LSB: Load O2CB cluster services at system boot.
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/o2cb; generated)
  Active: active (exited) since Fri 2024-06-28 17:04:53 UTC; 2 days ago
  Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  CPU: 12ms
 lampstack-vm systemd:Starting o2cb.service - LSB: Load O2CB cluster services at system boot
 lampstack-vm systemd:Started  o2cb.service - LSB: Load O2CB cluster services at system boot

But when I try to bring the o2cb online I see this error:
  root@lampstack-vm:~# service o2cb online
  checking debugfs...
  Loading filesystem "ocfs2_dlmfs": Unable to load filesystem "ocfs2_dlmfs" Failed

Looking in the syslogs I see:
 root@lampstack-vm:~# grep -i ocfs /var/log/syslog
 lampstack-vm systemd: Started ocfs2.service - LSB: Mount OCFS2 volumes at boot..
 lampstack-vm modprobe: FATAL: Module ocfs2_stackglue not found in directory /lib/modules/6.1.0-21-cloud-amd64
 lampstack-vm modprobe: FATAL: Module ocfs2_dlmfs not found in directory /lib/modules/6.1.0-21-cloud-amd64

My GCP VM kernel is version:
 root@lampstack-vm:~# hostnamectl
 Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
 Kernel: Linux 6.1.0-21-cloud-amd64

It's my understanding that an OCFS2 installation consists of two parts, the kernel module and the tools module.
I guess installing ocsf2-tools does not install the kernel module?
From other documentation it appears I need to install the linux-modules-extra package for my kernel.
I have installed the tools module, but I cannot locate the ocfs2 kernel module for Linux 6.1.0-21-cloud-amd64.
I tried to install linux-modules-extra like this:
  root@lampstack-vm:~# apt install linux-modules-extra-6.1.0-21-cloud-amd64
  E: Unable to locate package linux-modules-extra-6.1.0-21-cloud-amd64
  E: Couldn't find any package by glob linux-modules-extra-6.1.0-21-cloud-amd64

Where can I find the linux-modules-extra-6.1.0-21-cloud-amd64 package?
What are my options if the linux-modules-extra-6.1.0-21-cloud-amd64 package is not available?
